# How std::thread object copies argument?

Tags: c++11, g++, ubuntu-18.04, clang++, stdthread

### question updated !

I got a std::string object, and std::thread supposed to copy it into it's internal storage, why the code below still doesn't work?**(FIXED)**

If I detach t(f, 5, std::string(buf)), there are no output at all ! **(FIXED)**

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

void f(int i, const std::string &str) {
  printf("i = %d, str = %s\n", i, str.c_str());
}

void oops(int ival) {
  char *buf = new char[32]{0};
  snprintf(buf, 32, "%i", ival);
  // maybe danling pointer, if it's a danling pointer, the content of buf is undefined
  // in this program it happens to be 1999.
  std::thread t(f, 3, buf); 
  t.detach();

  delete [] buf; 
}

void not_oops(int ival) {
  char *buf = new char[32]{0};
  snprintf(buf, 32, "%i", ival);
  std::thread t(f, 5, std::string(buf));
  t.detach();

  delete [] buf;
}

int main() {
  oops(1992); // This is buggy
  not_oops(1999);
}
```

expected output:

```
i = 3, str = 1992
i = 5, str = 1999
```

actual output:

```
i = 3, str = 1999
i = 5, str = 1999
```

Comment: You need to add some delay in `main` to wait for results (maybe by using `this_thread::sleep_for()` ?). With two invocations of `detach`, `main` ends immediately. Your `not_oops` function works properly, you will see correct results when you fix delay problem.

Comment: Yes, in `oops` it's copying the value. The value is just a pointer though.

Comment: but the output is still not right...

Answer (score 0):

Your program finishes before it is complete, your function exits scope before thread is complete, killing it.

```
void oops(int ival) {
  char *buf = new char[32]{0};
  snprintf(buf, 32, "%i", ival);
  std::thread t(f, 3, buf); // maybe danling pointer
  t.detach();     // no more waiting for it

  delete [] buf;  // thread is not started yet (probably)    
} // thread is destroyed ,  and std::string dies.
```

Only way to make it work without vast changes to code, is to allow threads to be managed outside. Also you have to ensure that a new  std::string is created, or thread appears to use same storage for both.

```
void f(int i, const std::string &str) {
  printf("i = %d, str = %s\n", i, str.c_str());
}

std::thread *t;
void oops(int ival) {
  char *buf = new char[32]{0};
  snprintf(buf, 32, "%i", ival);
  t = new std::thread(f, 3, std::string(buf)); // maybe danling pointer
  //t.detach();

  delete [] buf; 
}

void not_oops(int ival) {
  char *buf = new char[32]{0};
  snprintf(buf, 32, "%i", ival);
  std::thread t(f, 5, std::string(buf)); // FIXME: why it won't work ?
  t.join();
  delete [] buf;
}

int main() {
  oops(1992); // This is buggy
  not_oops(1999);
  t->join();
  delete t;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, What if I don't want manage the std::thread object outside of the oops function? Why oops(1992) and oops(1999) both print 1999?